# Campaign Name in the wrapped URL

Tags: marketing-cloud

We are planning on using the Web Analytic Connector to allow the campaign name to be entered in the email properties.

Ideally we would like to be able to pull the Campaign Name from the email without entering this value. Is there anyway to get the Campaign Name from an assigned Campaign on an email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the [**Additional Email Attributes**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/)?  You can add the static text in the Properties page of your email. If they don't show in the Properties panel, SFMC Support can enable them for you.

[image: AEA1]

In your Web-Analytics Connector you can just reference it with the personalization string:

`&id=%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute1%%`

[image: AEA]

Comment: Thanks. That's how we have it now. I was just trying to eliminate the need to reenter that Campaign. My thought was if a campaign is assigned to the email no further work is needed.

Comment: I wish there was a personalization string for the built-in Campaign tagging.  It's only used for that dashboard and calendar that no one cares about.